# linking verb or helping verb

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I know after linking verb, Adjective and noun should be used,
Do 'should be, will be' serve as a linking verb or helping verbs in the following sentences?

1. John should be here by 2:00 PM.
2. You should stop eating fast food.
3. I will not be late
4. I will be waiting outside

Comment: [corrections: I know that after a linking verb, an adjective or noun should be used. ]

Answer (score -1):

Not so fast! You've misunderstood the term a bit. There is nothing wrong with that.

A linking verb is, as you stated before, followed by an adjective or a modified noun. Such verbs are: *get, become, keep, remain, seem, appear,* and so on.

> John should be **here (adverb of place)** by 2:00 PM.
>
> You should stop **eating(gerund)** fast food.
>
> I will not be **late(adverb of place).**
>
> I will be waiting **outside(adverb of place).**

Those are auxiliary or helping verbs.

You just mixed up their function in a sentence, failing to recognize a linking verb.

However, here is an example of a linking verb in usage:

She seemed *weary (adjective, complement)*.

In some instances, when the adjective starts with "a-", to-infinitive has to be inserted.

E.g.
She appeared to be alive. ( but not: appeared alive, as it sounds unnatural and incorrect. );

Because it's an adjective preceded by a verb and that adjective becomes the complement ultimately, we can now see how you recognize a linking verb.